# MS Access SQL to Select date range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to select a record with dates which has dates ( in range: form 1998 to 1999). I wrote the statement which did seem to work . Why?

```
SELECT *
FROM Factory
WHERE 
(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS dyear) BETWEEN '1998'  AND '1999'
```

Comment: Why not just do `WHERE date BETWEEN '1998-01-01' AND '1999-12-31'`?

Comment: @RCola why it shouldn't work?

Comment: MS Access showed some error which has no documentation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `YEAR()` to get the year from the date.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Factory
WHERE  YEAR(date) BETWEEN 1998 AND 1999
```

- [MSAccess YEAR()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/year.php)

Answer (score 2):

Applying the `Year()` function for *every* row in `Factory` will be a noticeable performance challenge if the table includes thousands of rows.  (Actually it would be a performance challenge for a smaller table, too, but you would be less likely to notice the hit in that case.)  A more efficient approach would be to index the `[date]` field and use indexed retrieval to limit the db engine's workload.

```
SELECT f.*
FROM Factory AS f
WHERE f.date >= #1998-1-1# AND f.date < #2000-1-1#;
```

Whenever possible, design your queries to take advantage of indexed retrieval.  That can improve performance dramatically.  As a simplistic rule of thumb: indexed retrieval = good; full table scan = bad.  Try to avoid full tables scans whenever possible.