# Microsoft Access SQL to query a date range ignoring the year

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to select records based on a range of month/day values, disregarding the year. I am querying an Access database, and I found a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790213/ms-access-sql-to-select-date-range) but it seems to select a range of years.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Factory
WHERE  YEAR(date) BETWEEN 1998 AND 1999
```

I have tried this query, but it only shows birthdays in the current year :

```
SELECT * FROM user where birthday Between #09/05# and #10/10#;
```

In my database the birthday column contains the year to count how old they are. What query can I use to perform what I want?

Comment: use #1991/12/31# to indicate date types in queries in access

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168529/sql-access-how-to-return-between-dates

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/examples-of-query-criteria-HA010066611.aspx

Comment: i just updated my question, i want to query my database without considering year in my "birthday" column in my database

Comment: my program wanna check birthday every year without considering year example : i wanna check user's birthday between 5 September until 10 October, how to query that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE (month(birthday) * 100) + day(birthday) between 0131 and 1231
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE birthday between #1991/12/31# and #1992/01/31#;

OR

SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE birthday between #12/31/1991# and #01/31/1992#;  

OR

SELECT * FROM 
user
WHERE birthday between #1991/12/31# and #1992/01/31#
```