# Microsoft Access SQL to query a date range without year

Tags: sql, ms-access

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207638/microsoft-access-sql-to-query-a-date-range-ignoring-the-year) but a bit different.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Cats_History.ID, Cats_History.TYPE, Cats_History.BEGDATE, Cats_History.ENDDATE, Cats_History.DESCRIPTION, Cats_History.LOSS, Cats_History.LOSSCURRENT
FROM Cats_History
WHERE (Month(Cats_History.BEGDATE)*100)+Day(Cats_History.BEGDATE) Between 101 And 131;
```

This works fine when specifying the month/day in the SQL. However if I replace 101 and 131 with [start] and [end], so that the user can enter values after clicking on my form button, I get incorrect results.

For example, if I enter 101 and 108 using the form, the correct January dates are displayed but October dates are also displayed as well.

```
SELECT Cats_History.ID, Cats_History.TYPE, Cats_History.BEGDATE, Cats_History.ENDDATE, Cats_History.DESCRIPTION, Cats_History.LOSS, Cats_History.LOSSCURRENT
FROM Cats_History
WHERE (Month(Cats_History.BEGDATE)*100)+Day(Cats_History.BEGDATE) Between [start] And [end];
```

If I try any dates other than January it seems to work fine also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Cats_History.ID, Cats_History.TYPE, Cats_History.BEGDATE, Cats_History.ENDDATE, Cats_History.DESCRIPTION, Cats_History.LOSS, Cats_History.LOSSCURRENT
FROM Cats_History
WHERE (Month(Cats_History.BEGDATE)*100)+Day(Cats_History.BEGDATE) Between CInt([start]) and CInt([end]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
SELECT Cats_History.ID, Cats_History.TYPE, Cats_History.BEGDATE
  , Cats_History.ENDDATE, Cats_History.DESCRIPTION, Cats_History.LOSS
  , Cats_History.LOSSCURRENT
FROM Cats_History
WHERE Month(Cats_History.BEGDATE) = 1
  AND Day(Cats_History.BEGDATE) BETWEEN ([start] % 100) AND ([end] % 100);
```

I'm not sure why you would get dates in October. Sounds like there may be an error in the math you use to generate `[start]` and `[end]`.

I suggest just using date values and simplifying the query to:

```
SELECT Cats_History.ID, Cats_History.TYPE, Cats_History.BEGDATE
  , Cats_History.ENDDATE, Cats_History.DESCRIPTION, Cats_History.LOSS
  , Cats_History.LOSSCURRENT
FROM Cats_History
WHERE Cats_History.BEGDATE BETWEEN [start] AND [end];
```

Comment: I am using MS Access.

Comment: @Andrew - What part of this fails in Access?

Comment: I edited my question to include the SQL that fails. When I am prompted and enter a January date range the results also display October (10th month) dates.

Comment: If I use your second SQL code it does not ignore the year though. Correct? I get a syntax error using your first code snippet. It highlights the % sign on the error. I'm not using any math to generate [start] and [end]. That's just the prompt where the user enters a month and day. E.g. 101 (for Jan 1st). And end of 108 (for Jan. 8th). I'm not sure why I am getting errors when using January values only. Also, when I try 101 to 131, it retrieves values for Oct, Nov and Dec. I am guessing there is some kind of value type situation like text vs integer.

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, the year is not ignored. Are you looking to only match the month and day regardless of year?
If you suspect type issues, you could force conversion to Integer values with `CInt([start])` and `CInt([end])`.

Comment: Yes it works correctly now using CInt([start]) and CInt([end]) !